# Doesn't AutoCompleteExtender work for asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to put an AutoCompleExtender in my project with this page :

```
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtMovie" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtautofromDB" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList2" 
MinimumPrefixLength="2"
CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="10" 
TargetControlID="txtMovie"
ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false" />
```

and server code is :

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string[] GetCompletionList2(string prefixText, int count)
{
    dt = Telephone.Search(prefixText);
    List<string> CountryNames = new List<string>();

    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        CountryNames.Add(dr[0].ToString());

    }
    return CountryNames.ToArray();
}
```

but it does not work.

Comment: `but it does'nt work. help me.`; you're going to have to help us help you. We have ***no idea what it means*** when you say `but it does'nt work.`

Comment: the array that returned is not empty but txtMovie does'nt show any things.